# HERE: Return Observable While Waiting statechange To Finish Then Subscribe To It

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, heremaps

I am encountering a hard time to solve these 2 issues and still working on it. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

1.) I have a **map.service** with this function.

```
readKML(file): any {
    const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const reader = new HERE_MAP.data.kml.Reader(exportUrl);

    // Parse the document
    reader.parse();

    reader.addEventListener('statechange', (evt) => {
      if (evt.state === HERE_MAP.data.AbstractReader.State.READY) {


        return of({
          markers: ['test'],
          lines: ['test]
        });

      }
      if (evt.state === HERE_MAP.data.AbstractReader.State.ERROR) {
        this.message.error('KML parsing error');
         return of(null);
      }
    });
  }
```

This function is being called in the **component** and expect to get the return data.

```
this.map.service.readKML(file)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  }
)
```

The problem is im getting an error

```
this.map.readKML(...).subscribe is not a function
```

**Expectation:**

*The data should received if the stateChange is equal to 'READY'.*

2.) The service will be called at the same time with different param value and expected to have different returns if number 1 is okay.

However, this can be solved if 1 is still be an issue.

```
this.map.service.readKML(file1)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('one', data);
      }
    )

this.map.service.readKML(file1)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('two', data);
      }
    )
```

If you guys have an idea on how to fix this or other approach much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue:** First why your code failed:
`addEventListener` is an async operation and is returning void because `of` is not even reached by the time your function has already returned from `readKML`.

```
readKML(file): any {
    const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const reader = new HERE_MAP.data.kml.Reader(exportUrl);

    // Parse the document
    reader.parse();

// 'addEventListener' is an async operation which returns void, so you are returning a void
    reader.addEventListener('statechange', (evt) => { 
      if (evt.state === HERE_MAP.data.AbstractReader.State.READY) {


        return of({ // reached here after already returning void
          markers: ['test'],
          lines: ['test']
        });

      }
      if (evt.state === HERE_MAP.data.AbstractReader.State.ERROR) {
        this.message.error('KML parsing error');
         return of(null);
      }
    });
  }
```

**Fix:** you need to return an observable. So wrap the `addEventListener` into an observable. Complete the observable once the response comes.

Since you are returning observable, every time that you call this `readKML` method a new observable would be created.

```
     readKML(file): any {
    const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const reader = new HERE_MAP.data.kml.Reader(exportUrl);

    reader.parse();

    return new Observable((subscriber) => { // return observable
        reader.addEventListener('statechange', (evt) => {
            if (evt.state === HERE_MAP.data.AbstractReader.State.READY) {

                subscriber.next({
                    markers: ['test'],
                    lines: ['test']
                }); // return response
                subscriber.complete(); // always complete for next so only single reponse goes for single method call (cold observable)
            }
            if (evt.state === HERE_MAP.data.AbstractReader.State.ERROR) {
                this.message.error('KML parsing error');
                subscriber.next(null); // you can also throw error ` throw throwError(response); `;
                subscriber.complete();
            }
        });
    });
}
```